# Spring MVC + RequestParam as Map + get URL array parameters not working

Tags: arrays, list, spring-mvc, dynamic, parameters

I'm currently working on an API controller. This controller should be able to catch any - **unknown** - parameter and put it in a `Map` object. Now I'm using this code to catch all parameters and put them in a `Map`

```
public String processGetRequest(final @RequestParam Map params)
```

Now the url I call is as follows:

```
server/api.json?action=doSaveDeck&Card_IDS[]=1&Card_IDS[]=2&Card_IDS[]=3
```

Then I print out the parameters, for debugging purposes, with this piece of code:

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    for (Object objKey : params.keySet()) {
        logger.debug(objKey.toString() + ": " + params.get(objKey));
    }
}
```

The result of that is:

```
10:43:01,224 DEBUG ApiRequests:79 - action: doSaveDeck
10:43:01,226 DEBUG ApiRequests:79 - Card_IDS[]: 1
```

But the expected result should be something like:

```
10:43:XX DEBUG ApiRequests:79 - action: doSaveDeck
10:43:XX DEBUG ApiRequests:79 - Card_IDS[]: 1
10:43:XX DEBUG ApiRequests:79 - Card_IDS[]: 2
10:43:XX DEBUG ApiRequests:79 - Card_IDS[]: 3
```

Or atleast tell me that the Card_IDS is an `String[] / List<String>` and therefore should be casted. I also tried casting the parameter to a `List<String>` manually but that does not work either:

```
for (Object objKey : params.keySet()) {
    if(objKey.equals(NameConfiguration.PARAM_NAME_CARDIDS)){ //Never reaches this part
        List<String> ids = (List<String>)params.get(objKey); 

        for(String id : ids){
            logger.debug("Card: " + id);
        }
    } else {
        logger.debug(objKey + ": " + params.get(objKey));
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me how to get the array `Card_IDS` - **It must be dynamically** - from the `Map params` by using the `NameConfiguration.PARAM_NAME_CARDIDS`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you request a `Map` annotated with `@RequestParam` Spring creates a map containing all request parameter name/value pairs. If there are two pairs with the same name, then only one can be in the map. So it's essentially a `Map<String, String>`

You can access **all** parameters through a `MultiValueMap`:

```
public String processGetRequest(@RequestParam MultiValueMap parameters) {
```

This map is essentially a `Map<String, List<String>>`. So parameters with the same name would be in the same list.