# Spring MVC N number of parameters mapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc, url-mapping

I tried binding N numbers of parameters in a URL like this

```
/web/appl/<applname>/rule/<rulename>/<attrname1>/<attrval1>/<attrname2>/<attrval2>/.../<attrnameN>/<attrvalN>
```

with

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/web/appl/{applname}/rule/{rulename}/{attributes}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Object GetService(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("attributes") Map<String, Object> map,
                @PathVariable("applname") String applname, @PathVariable("rulename") String rulename)
                throws Exception {
                  ...
                }
```

but could not get values of `<attrval1>/<attrname2>/<attrval2>/.../<attrnameN>/<attrvalN>`

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355168/spring-mvc-requestparam-as-map-get-url-array-parameters-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`String urlAttributes = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);`

and get whole URL. After that parse this URL according to your needs like if you did not get

`<attrval1>/<attrname2>/<attrval2>/.../<attrnameN>/<attrvalN>`

in proper sequence then you can throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Spring MVC does not provide such a solution. You can consider the [Matrix Variables](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-matrix-variables) as an alternative.

If you prefer sticking to your current URI scheme then you have to implement a solution yourself. One approach is to use a path pattern. Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/web/appl/{applname}/rule/{rule name}/**")
public Object getService(HttpServletRequest request,
            @PathVariable("applname") String applname ...) {
    String attributesPart = new AntPathMatcher()
        .extractPathWithinPattern("/web/appl/{applname}/rule/{rule name}/**", 
            request.getServletPath());
    ...
```

You could implement your argument resolver that does that. Something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/web/appl/{applname}/rule/{rule name}/**")
public Object getService(@MyAttributes Map<String, String> attributes,
            @PathVariable("applname") String applname ...) {
```