# Map<String, String> as @RequestParam in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm new to spring and I'm trying to add a `@RequestParam` of type `Map<String, String>` to my controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Model search(@RequestParam(value = "searchTerm", required = false) final String searchTerm,
        @RequestParam(value = "filters", required = false) Map<String, String> filters,
        final Model model) {
```

And in the URL it looks like this:

```
localhost/search?searchTerm=factory&filters[name]=factory1&filters[name]=factory2
```

But every time, filters is `null`, no matter what I do.

Can this be done? Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC + RequestParam as Map + get URL array parameters not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355168/spring-mvc-requestparam-as-map-get-url-array-parameters-not-working)

Comment: Hi vzamanillo, so the only way would be by iterating through all of the request parameters? I cannot declare, lets say, two request parameters that are of type map?

Answer (score 1):

Using Map with @RequestParam for multiple params
If the method parameter is Map or MultiValueMap then the **map is populated with all query** string names and values. Following will be mapped with /employees/234/messages?sendBy=mgr&date=20160210

```
@RequestMapping("{id}/messages")
public String handleEmployeeMessagesRequest (@PathVariable("id") String employeeId,
                                        @RequestParam Map<String, String> queryMap,
                                        Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("msg", "employee request by id and query map : "+
              employeeId+", "+queryMap.toString());
    return "my-page";
}
```

Where employeeId = "234" and queryMap = {sendBy=mgr, date=20160210}