# How to insert a map<Integer, String> as @RequestParam with Postman

Tags: java, spring, postman

first of all, sorry for my english, it's not my main language, and I'm not sure the question is fully understandable.

I need to do some queries after receiving a Map as a @RequestParam of a Rest Web Service.

I'm trying to call the web service with Postman, and here is the full POST request
    http://localhost:8080/CDRestApi/rest/cd/esibizione/getIdUdFromIstanzaMetadatoByMap/5/map?25=ALAN&26=IANESELLI

This is my WS code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/getIdUdFromIstanzaMetadatoByMap/{id}/map" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
@ResponseBody
public String selectIstanzaMetadato(@PathVariable Long id,
                                    @RequestParam (value="map", required=true) Map<Integer,String> mapQuery) {

    Integer key = 25;
    System.out.println(mapQuery.get(key));
    return mapQuery.get(key).toString();
}
```

And this is the postman answer:

```
{
"timestamp": 1505834218902,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/CDRestApi/rest/cd/esibizione/getIdUdFromIstanzaMetadatoByMap/5/map"
```

}

the System.out print is:

```
17:16:58,891 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4) null
```

I suppose the mapQuery object has no value, because it is not correctly valorized

I have already seen those posts, but they were not useful to me:
[Map<String, String> as @RequestParam in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916923/mapstring-string-as-requestparam-in-spring-mvc) 
and 
[Spring MVC + RequestParam as Map + get URL array parameters not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355168/spring-mvc-requestparam-as-map-get-url-array-parameters-not-working)

Do I miss the correct Postman POST request ? or it is a problem of the webservice itself ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'll add into the question

Comment: Does it work if you do a `Map<String, String>` and `String key = "25";`  instead of `Integer key = 25;` ?

Comment: no, it returns the same error

Comment: I also tried to pass the map K/V as json into "raw" Postman tab, and not as described above. But I received wrong request message

Comment: Wait, I did a full clean of my WildFLy Application Server, and now the Standard output says 
    17:48:45,846 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4) DIMENSION: 2
    17:48:45,846 INFO  [stdout] (default task-4) ALAN
But the Postman says:
    Unexpected 'A'

Comment: Just Unexpected 'A'? Can you show a screenshot of postmans response?

Comment: My guess is that the parameters should be inside the request body, and should be named `map[25]` and `map[26]`, i.e. the requestbody should be `map[25]=ALAN&map[26]=IANESELLI`. But you normally choose how to annotate your method based on what you intend to send, not the reverse.

Comment: OK, now seems all correct, 
I removed the return mapQuery.get(key).toString(); statement and put a more correct Gson gson = new Gson(); return gson.toJson(mapQuery);

Now it works, thanks a lot!! where do I vote your answer ?
But what if I need absolutely to have a <Integer, String> map ?

Comment: I resolved this getting the map<String,String> and converting it into a map<Integer, String>. Sadly the return gson.toJso(mapQuery) worked with a Map>Integer,String> but any other operation with the map (IE. accessing a data) failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this getting the map and converting it into a map.

```
Map<Integer, String> mappaQuery = mapQuery.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue));
```

It is not efficient, but it worked for the test purposes of Postman call; in the real call of the WS, I can pass a proper Map object.